# how can i calculate the degree of agreement between two methods

Tags: spss, agreement-statistics

I have a sample of 26 learners and I used two different methods to identify their personalities. My problem is I am not that good in statistics and I want variables that I can use within SPSS to calculate the degree of agreement between these two methods (i.e the learner 1 has X as his personality in method 1 and X as his personality in method 2....).
Besides, can I use some graphs in SPSS to generate plots for each method.
This can help readers to easily see if there is a consistent results in the two methods or not. Thank you.

PS: My data set is as follows: **Learner:** (1,2,3...26) | **personality with Method1:** (introvert, moderate or extrovert) | **personality with Method2:** (introvert, moderate or extrovert)

Comment: Are there only the three personality types (introvert, moderate, and extrovert)?

Comment: Yes only 3 types

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, we have 26 learners that were identified as having one of three personality types using 2 methods.

Next, we will assign the value of '1' for 'Agreement'. For example, if Method1 = 'Introvert' and Method2 = 'Introvert' then '1'. We can see the results below for all 26 learners:

[image]

As you can see, we have agreement between the two methods, 17 out of 26 times, which is 65.4% agreement. I would assume the higher the level of agreement here, the better, but we can discuss the goals of this agreement, if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what i mean. however, i wanted to use some statistical variables and interpret from there. I know few statistical methods but i dont know if they can be used in my case (e.g Kappa variable, Bland-Altman Plots). Or do you know any which i can use in SPSS to solve my problem. Thank you again for all your time and guidance.

Comment: Ah no problem! I am not familiar with SPSS (I am a SAS/R User), but this [link](http://www.stattutorials.com/SPSS/TUTORIAL-SPSS-Interrater-Reliability-Kappa.htm) looks very helpful!

Comment: Thank you alot.if you dont mind me asking is there any name for your method presented above? is it some sort of calculating distance or? again Thank you for all your support

Comment: It is important to note that Kappa is a valid statistic for assessing agreement of tests, in addition to interrater reliability, whereas that article says "agreement between two people".

Comment: The simple method described above is assessing the agreement between Method1 and Method2. It isn't grounded in statistics, it is simply looking at the number of agreements divided by the number of subjects to tell us how often Method1 and Method2 provide the same test result. The assumption here is that if Method1 identifies a learner as an introvert and Method2 identifies a learner as either an extrovert or a moderate, the miss in agreement is of equal weight. I would argue it is a bigger issue if one test tells us that a learner is an introvert and the other test labels them as an extrovert.

Comment: Ah ok, i may use your method (manually) and a valid static method (Kappa using SPSS) to validate my method. Thank you for all your support

Comment: I would highly recommend walking through the link that I provided as it will provide you with the SPSS implementation for a statistic (Kappa) that will assist you in explaining the agreement between Method1 and Method2, if the simple method that I provided is of little value. I tend to keep my analyses as simple as needed, but having something like Kappa is always handy!

Comment: That sounds like an excellent approach. I am glad that I could be of assistance!